# Where to write code for design in Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, surfaceview

I'm trying to build a custom Cordova plugin for android platform. As of now i'm able to write the activity code in `.java` file but i don't know where and how i have to write design code (XML layout) in plugin. My layout code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="dev.edmt.androidcamerarecognitiontext.MainActivity">

  <SurfaceView
      android:id="@+id/surface_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:text="No Text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please give me ideas about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ben Morris, Thank you for your suggestion.

I think this solution may help others, I have checked lot of forums to add the design in plugin but i didn't get proper solution so i have implemented `SurfaceView`  in the `.java` (Which extends from `CordovaPlugin`) file as bellow

```
  Context activity = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();


  SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(activity);
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        Gravity.CENTER);

  cordova.getActivity().addContentView(surfaceView, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Plugin Development Guide?

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html

Comment: Hi Ben, previously i have checked these but i din't get anything about design in cordova plugin. Do you have any view on this?

Comment: To be honest I've always just used HTML for my UI when writing plugins.

Comment: Under which folder you are placing the HTML files and what i not understood was, how we can include HTML with java